# Power Bi timeseries correlation with events

Tags: powerbi, timeserieschart

I am actually working on a Power Bi timeseries visual, to show the changes of air-quality during the corona-crisis. To show the correlation, I want to display the corona time-frame. Is there any possibility to make this visual.

Thanks, Andreas

Comment: It's unclear what kind of visual you are talking about.

Comment: What correlation are you trying to show? "air quality index" vs. "number of Corona deaths"? What's the timeseries then?